# NSTableView multiple Selections

Tags: iphone, ios5, selection, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView`  with multiple selections enabled

If I select items and scroll the list  back and forth they are remember and shown and selected  (blue background).
Using the  `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`  and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`  I am able to keep my own array of selected items.

that part works well.

However If I then use the `sectionForSectionIndexTitle`  and jump to a letter The selection appears to be forgotten  even `indexPathForSelectedRows`  appears to have been reset and is now empty.

My own array remembers that an item is selected and I can set the cell.selected  in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  but the instant I move the list it is forgotten again

Any ideas  is this a bug  or how do you retain the selection list when jumping to a letter

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using an `NSMutableArray` of selected row values, it may be possible to keep track of the selected rows in the table yourself.  Then it would be a matter of calling `-selectRowAtIndexPath:animated` on the last object in the array to restore the selections.

As for the bug: what could possibly be happening when the table jumps to a selected letter, is a stray `-reloadData` which would forget the selected row(s).

Comment: Thanks  storying row values may be a great idea

Answer (score 1):

Remember the UITableViewCells are there to display your data only and by no means they have a 1-to-1 relationship with your "model" as the are queued and reused when necessary (i.e. you may have thousands of items on display in a tableview but only a handful of instances of UITableViewCell allocated).

So you need to keep track of the selected / deselected items in a mutable array and make sure that you check for the presence of that item in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method and then update the cell properties to represent your data.

Comment: Thanks  I do just that  and while scroll up and down the list that works

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening because your cells are reused. Do not reuse the cells(you are not using your cells efficiently). otherwise,

You can store the selection by yourself in an array and use it later for your purpose.!